# Deleted old version of Documents do not appear in the Trashcan

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

Using Alfresco Community 6.2.2.

I'm deleting only old versions of the document:

```
CmisObject obj = session.getObject("9c5e6f3f-effd-448d-8946-13d16a46b28d;1.16");
obj.delete(false);
```

As the result, they deleted in the UI but not appear in the Trashcan.
Also I can't find them by GET /deleted-nodes/{nodeId} request.

So where can I find those deleted old versions? Is there possibility to restore them?
And is there possibility to permanently delete those old versions to free storage space?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but I would expect that the versions deleted don't go to the trash (archive://Spacestore) at all and therefore there may be no api to restore. The node will be deleted and the document versions content stored on the disk will be finally removed (copied to the contentstore.deleted) after the default time of 14 days. There is even no store definition for an `archive://version2Store` which would be the expected store name for a versionsore trashcan.

If you want to reduce the required time to free up the disk space you need to configure `system.content.orphanProtectDays` in alfresco-global.properties which defaults to `14`

Please Check also [Repository concepts](https://docs.alfresco.com/6.2/concepts/dev-repository-concepts.html) and [Understanding Alfresco Content Deletion](https://blyx.com/2014/08/18/understanding-alfresco-content-deletion/)

Comment: So there is no possibility to restore deleted old versions?

Answer (score 0):

To Delete Node permanently,add **cm:temporary** aspect before delete.
By applying that aspect content will bypass trashcan.

Comment: author asked about versions not the main node so your suggestion does not apply